# How to change class instance?

Tags: python, magic-methods

This is my Class, below i made two instances h1 and h2, each has different names, then i want to add h2 to h1 like h1.money + h2.money then we supposed to get h1.money = 100. but i dunno how to do that.

```
class Bank:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.money = 50

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Bank):
            self.money = self.money + other.money
            return Bank(self.name)

    def info(self):
        print(self.money)


h1 = Bank('Br1')
h2 = Bank('Br2')
h1 = h1 + h2

print(h1.name, h1.money)
```

output:
Br1 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you modify the money, you should return `self`.

```py
class Bank:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.money = 50

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Bank):
            self.money = self.money + other.money
            # return Bank(self.name)
            return self

    def info(self):
        print(self.money)


h1 = Bank('Br1')
h2 = Bank('Br2')
h1 = h1 + h2

print(h1.name, h1.money)
# Br1 100
```

Answer (score 1):

`Bank.__init__` should take an additional argument to let you set the initial value.

```
class Bank:
    def __init__(self, name, money=50):
        self.name = name
        self.money = money

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Bank):
            money = self.money + other.money
            return Bank(self.name, money)
        return NotImplemented

    def info(self):
        print(self.money)
```

`NotImplemented` is returned when `other` is not an instance of `Bank` so that `other.__radd__` gets a chance to define the operation. In general, `__add__` should not modify either of its arguments (but see below).

You might also consider whether when (or if) it makes sense to add two `Bank` instances together. For example, what if the two `Bank`s you are adding have different names; do you really want to just take the first one's name, ignoring the second?

Finally, if you really want to modify a bank in-place as suggested by your original code, implement `Bank.__iadd__` as well:

```
def __iadd__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Bank):
        self.money += other.money
        return self
    return NotImplemented
```

Then

```
h1 += h2  # h1.__iadd__(h2)
```